# Is there any way to get the modified string from memory?

Tags: c#, string

I just want to clarify my thoughts string -
The string is immutable we cannot change or modify the existing string if we do any modification it will extend the memory space in the heap and it will be considered as a new string on the same memory location.

In the below method, I'm replacing the string(name) and storing the changed string to the same variable. now we get the modified string. is there any way to retrieve the original string(using memory address)?
If we invoke the Dispose() method will the original string cleared from memory?

```
  public void TestString(string value)
    {
        string name = "Test ever";
        name = name.Replace("ever", "always");
        Console.WriteLine(name+ "- TestMethod");
    }
```

[image: Memory Allocation for String]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See following : https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2016/11/15/exploring-memory-allocation-and-strings.html?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 3):

You just need to keep track of the original string's address. The easiest way to do that is store it in a variable.

```
public void TestString(string value)
{
    string name = "Test ever";
    var originalString = name; //Save the address
    name = name.Replace("ever", "always");
    Console.WriteLine(name+ "- TestMethod");
    Console.WriteLine("The original string was " + originalString);
}
```